# How to migrate from IIB to AppConnect

Tags: ibm-cloud, integration

Good afternoon.

Can you help me find information about "How to migrate all configurations and modules from IIB to App Connect".

I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it on developer's page:
https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2018/12/13/app-connect-enterprise-v11-migration-approach/
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTTDS_11.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bh23410_.htm